# How many ways are there to divide 9 distinct candies into groups of 2 or 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Recently, I found a question involving dividing distinct candies into groups of specific sizes, and the specific one I found goes as follows:

> There are $9$ distinct candies in a large bucket. There are also multiple smaller bags that may contain either $2$ or $3$ candies each. How many ways can the candies from the bucket be divided into the smaller bags? All candies must be divided into a bag, and the smaller bags are all identical to each other.

My initial thoughts was to find all the possible bag combinations. So there would either be $3$ bags each containing $3$ candies, or $3$ bags of $2$ candies and $1$ bag of $3$ candies. But I'm not exactly sure how to proceed in finding the amount of possibilities for either case. Additionally, I figured that this method might take a long time for more complex scenarios, and was wondering if there was any more efficient method or a formula for this kind of a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For three bags of three, you choose three candies out of nine for the first bag, three out of six for the second bag, and three out of three for the third bag, giving ${9 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3}{3 \choose 3}=\frac {9!}{3!3!3!}$.  Then as the bags are identical, we don't care what order they were filled in so we have to divide by another $3!$ for that.  The other is attacked similarly but the bag with three candies is distinct now.